# nexus: 331: cd: can’t cd to ../jre/bin

Tags: nexus, sonatype, nexus3

We are using Nexus3 - 3.23.0-03

while starting up our Nexus container it gives us below warning

“Removing .lock file

removed ‘/nexus-data/lock’

/sonatype/nexus/bin/nexus: 331: cd: can’t cd to …/jre/bin

2020-11-30 11:57:25,441+0100 INFO [FelixStartLevel] *SYSTEM org.sonatype.nexus.pax.logging.NexusLogActivator - start
Nexus not started yet.”

but later nexus gets up & functional , we would like to know if its a bug/error/having less impact or its issue with Nexus startup scripts so that we can ignore this or consider this to be resolved,

Please suggest or advise. Thanks!

Regards,

SAMURAI

Comment: How are you starting NXRM?  The default executable doesn't have a cd in it that I'm aware of, so I suspect a custom solution.

Comment: @joedragons  we are using debian buster for nexus docker container and have startup according to that, we are executing startup from this path /sonatype/nexus/bin/nexus  , its just show this error but nexus works fine. what else would you need to debug.

Comment: Okie, I'm unfamiliar with that solution, I think that's a Q for the people who provided the dockerfile.